# Why does gcc -ansi remove the declarations of cosf and the like?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c89

You probably think I am completely crazy and terribly bad at programming. One of those may be the case, but please read my findings.

Yes, I `#include <math.h>`

[Full Code can be found here.](https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/ch4-flag)( I was trying to make it ansi compliant to get it to compile on VS2010, It through an error about mixed code and declaration, and fminf() missing. I was surprised that VS2010 cared about mixed code and declaration with default warning levels. I recall 2008 not caring, but could be wrong. )

Here is the gcc output when using the c89/-ansi standard. note the implicit declarations of functions. There are a few others about unused parameters, but we don't care about those for now. ( needed for signature to register call backs with GLUT)

*When I run the application using the c89 or ansi standard, it produces the wrong output, much like the math functions are not behaving as expected.*

```
$ STANDARD=-std=c89 make -f Makefile.Unix
gcc -std=c89 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o file-util.o file-util.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
gcc -std=c89 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o gl-util.o gl-util.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
gcc -std=c89 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o meshes.o meshes.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
In file included from meshes.c:12:
vec-util.h: In function ‘vec_length’:
vec-util.h:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqrtf’
meshes.c: In function ‘calculate_flag_vertex’:
meshes.c:48: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sinf’
meshes.c:50: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cosf’
gcc -std=c89 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o flag.o flag.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
In file included from flag.c:18:
vec-util.h: In function ‘vec_length’:
vec-util.h:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqrtf’
flag.c: In function ‘update_p_matrix’:
flag.c:58: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fminf’
flag.c: In function ‘mouse’:
flag.c:252: warning: unused parameter ‘x’
flag.c:252: warning: unused parameter ‘y’
flag.c: In function ‘keyboard’:
flag.c:261: warning: unused parameter ‘x’
flag.c:261: warning: unused parameter ‘y’
flag.c: At top level:
vec-util.h:1: warning: ‘vec_cross’ defined but not used
vec-util.h:13: warning: ‘vec_normalize’ defined but not used
gcc -o flag file-util.o gl-util.o meshes.o flag.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGL -lglut -lGLEW
```

Now using the c99 standard the implicit declaration of function messages are gone.

```
$ STANDARD=-std=c99 make -f Makefile.Unix
gcc -std=c99 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o file-util.o file-util.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
gcc -std=c99 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o gl-util.o gl-util.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
gcc -std=c99 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o meshes.o meshes.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
gcc -std=c99 -Wextra -Wall -pedantic  -c -o flag.o flag.c -I/usr/X11R6/include
flag.c: In function ‘mouse’:
flag.c:252: warning: unused parameter ‘x’
flag.c:252: warning: unused parameter ‘y’
flag.c: In function ‘keyboard’:
flag.c:261: warning: unused parameter ‘x’
flag.c:261: warning: unused parameter ‘y’
flag.c: At top level:
vec-util.h:1: warning: ‘vec_cross’ defined but not used
vec-util.h:13: warning: ‘vec_normalize’ defined but not used
gcc -o flag file-util.o gl-util.o meshes.o flag.o -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lGL -lglut -lGLEW
```

*When using the c99 standard the program behaves as desired and expected.*

### The Question

Why would using the -ansi flag seemingly remove the declarations from math.h ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the [`GCC Builtins documentation`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), you'll see that `sinf` and `cosf` functions (and many more related ones) are introduced in the `C99` standard.

Comment: Hmm They are seemingly removed, because they are in fact not there. -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic were my compile flags at school and I was fairly sure we used sinf() and the like. I will have to go look at that. Thanks! Accepting answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `-ansi` for modern code. Despite the current version of ANSI C being aligned with ISO9899-1999 (C99), `-ansi` has been permanently assigned to mean "legacy mode" by gcc. Just use `-std=c99` if you're compiling C99 code. It's the modern equivalent.

Comment: And be sure to slap any GCC maintainers you meet for their atrocious misuse of the term `ansi`.

Comment: And give them an extra few slaps for leaving `-Dlinux=1` and `-Dunix=1` in the default preprocessor options, breaking any conformant program that uses symbols with these names unless you use `-ansi` or a `-std` option to remove them.